# CopyFromRecordset throws OutOfMemoryException

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, excel-automation

There are several threads that are close to my issue, but I haven't found a solution that is really applicable to my situation.

I have a .NET 2.0 (yeah yeah I know) WinForms application that reads a large amount of information (85 columns x 82236 rows) into an ADO recordset. I am then trying to use Excel automation to copy that recordset into an Excel spreadsheet. My application is throwing an OutOfMemoryException on the following line

```
worksheet.Range("A6").copyfromrecordset(recordset)
```

Using Excel 2010 I should be well within the limits for rows and/or columns. I have set the default save type to XLSX. I have 8GB physical memory on my machine, which should be ample to perform this operation. This is driving me crazy and I have no clue what could be causing it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is it a 64bit machine? Have you compiled 64bit executable? If not - your app is limited to 4Gb or less.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter If it is running on 32bit or as a 32bit process, it is most likely limited to only 2GB. It can be increased though (but it is not by default). Also look on  [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits) for more information.